# Select Multiple Rows From Same Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables '**book**' and '**category**'. How can I display *all* the rows from my 'book' table? Note, there is a join between *category(book table)* and *cat_name(category table*).

**book** table

```
id   category    title
1    2           a title here
2    2           a title here
3    1           a title here
4    Comedy      a title here
5    1           a title here
6    Horror      a title here
```

**category** table

```
id       cat_name   
----     -------         
1        Language
2        Kids
```

Currently I am using the following sql query, it only seems to display rows that have a number for the category, whereas I want **all** the data. Currently my html table doesn't display rows 4 and 6.

```
SELECT b.id, b.title, b.category, b.author, b.isbn, b.publicationYear,
        c.cat_name
        FROM book AS b
        INNER JOIN category AS c ON b.category = c.id
```

Sample of my php

```
echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['title'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['cat_name'] . '</td>';   
echo '<td>' . $row['author'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['isbn'] . '</td>';
```

Quite new to php/mysql so any advice or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `inner join` and this will return only matching item. If you want all item from left table use `left join` instead

```
    SELECT b.id, 
           b.title, 
           b.category, 
           b.author, 
           b.isbn, 
           b.publicationYear,
           c.cat_name
    FROM book AS b
    left JOIN 
    category AS c 
    ON
    b.category = c.id
```

UPDATE :

Doing left join will show null for the `cat_name` where it does not match with the `category` table

Work around would be as

```
SELECT 
b.id, 
b.title, 
b.category, 
b.author, 
b.isbn, 
b.publicationYear,
case 
 when cast(b.category as unsigned)= 0 then b.category
 else c.cat_name 
end as cat_name 
FROM book AS b
left JOIN category AS c ON b.category = c.id
```

Comment: Also in the long run "Comedy" and "Horror" should be moved over to the category table and only be referenced by category id. Mixing category ids and verbatim names in book.category is bad design ...

Comment: Yes since for non matching item `cat_name` becomes `null`, I have updated the answer with work-around.

Comment: @Hartmut I realise "Comedy" and "Horror" should be moved over to the category table however these are added via Giigle Books Api and I haven't figured out how to do this yet!

Answer (score 0):

try with this i think it solved your problem

```
SELECT b.id, 
       b.title, 
       b.category, 
       b.author, 
       b.isbn, 
       b.publicationYear,
       c.cat_name
FROM book AS b , category AS c
WHERE b.category = c.id
```